# How to remove duplicate product with same product ID in Woocommerce?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I updated the database. After the update I was faced with duplicate products in Woocommerce -- even though I didn't have duplicate products in database.

I deleted the transient but it's not fixed. I'd appreciate it if you guide me on how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Products]

[image: Database]

The below block shows the list of active plugins

```
+------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+----------+
| name                                           | status | update                       | version  |
+------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+----------+
| wc-abandoned-carts-by-small-fish-analytics     | active | none                         | 2.6.2    |
| admin-menu-search                              | active | none                         | 1.2      |
| woo-advanced-shipment-tracking                 | active | available                    | 3.1.4    |
| woo-auto-coupons                               | active | none                         | 1.3.2    |
| better-search-replace                          | active | none                         | 1.3.3    |
| bookly-responsive-appointment-booking-tool     | active | none                         | 18.9     |
| bookly-addon-pro                               | active | none                         | 3.1      |
| code-snippets                                  | active | none                         | 2.14.0   |
| commercegurus-commercekit                      | active | none                         | 1.1.7    |
| customizer-export-import                       | active | none                         | 0.9.2    |
| delete-duplicate-posts                         | active | none                         | 4.4.7    |
| elementor                                      | active | none                         | 3.0.13   |
| elementor-pro                                  | active | available                    | 3.0.5    |
| essential-addons-for-elementor-lite            | active | none                         | 4.3.6    |
| essential-addons-elementor                     | active | available                    | 4.2.1    |
| export-import-menus                            | active | none                         | 1.6.0    |
| facebook-for-woocommerce                       | active | available                    | 1.9.11   |
| kliken-marketing-for-google                    | active | none                         | 1.0.6    |
| jet-engine                                     | active | available                    | 2.5.2    |
| kirki                                          | active | none                         | 3.1.5    |
| mailchimp-for-woocommerce                      | active | none                         | 2.4.7    |
| one-click-demo-import                          | active | none                         | 2.6.1    |
| payment-gateways-by-user-roles-for-woocommerce | active | none                         | 1.2.3    |
| seo-by-rank-math                               | active | available                    | 1.0.52.1 |
| redux-framework                                | active | available                    | 4.1.21   |
| google-site-kit                                | active | none                         | 1.20.0   |
| smart-variations-images-premium                | active | none                         | 4.0.75   |
| string-locator                                 | active | none                         | 2.4.1    |
| analogwp-templates                             | active | none                         | 1.7.5    |
| transients-manager                             | active | none                         | 1.8.1    |
| updraftplus                                    | active | available                    | 1.16.29  |
| woo-variation-swatches                         | active | available                    | 1.1.0    |
| woocommerce                                    | active | none                         | 4.7.0    |
| woocommerce-advanced-bulk-edit                 | active | none                         | 4.5      |
| advanced-product-labels-for-woocommerce        | active | available                    | 1.1.16.4 |
| woocommerce-attribute-images                   | active | none                         | 1.2.0    |
| woocommerce-brands                             | active | none                         | 1.6.10   |
| woocommerce-composite-products2                | active | none                         | 7.1.1    |
| woocommerce-currency-converter-widget          | active | none                         | 1.6.23   |
| woocommerce-email-test                         | active | version higher than expected | 2.1      |
| order-emails-log-for-woocommerce               | active | version higher than expected | 2.0      |
| woocommerce-order-status-manager               | active | none                         | 1.9.2    |
| woocommerce-product-bundles                    | active | none                         | 6.4.0    |
| woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers           | active | none                         | 1.9.5    |
| woocommerce-gateway-stripe                     | active | none                         | 4.5.5    |
| weight-based-shipping-for-woocommerce          | active | none                         | 5.3.7    |
| wordpress-importer                             | active | none                         | 0.7      |
| xforwoocommerce                                | active | none                         | 1.2.8    |
| yith-woocommerce-pre-order-premium             | active | none                         | 1.5.9    |
+------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+----------+
```

Also I found I have duplicate product on category page with different price while they have same price in inner pages!

Comment: Do you have any plugin, like the admin column, that add/edit features on the product list page? If you edit one, is the other also edited? Meaning both links on your screen are going to the same URL and same content? Is it happening for all your products, or only a certain one or type (simple, variable)? When creating a new product, does it happens?

Comment: Technically this should not be possible, and most likely it's a UI bug showing the same item twice rather than it being duplicated product in the database.

Comment: @Mtxz I listed the active plugins, I think I didn't have any plugins for managing the product list of page.

Comment: @MichaelHabib When I using the filter the duplicate item disappearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact I had two issue. the first issue was duplicate product in product list page, that I figured it out the issue relate the some codes like this:

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status');
function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;
    // only change query on WooCommerce loops
    if ( is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy())) {
        $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
        $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
        $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
    }
    return $posts_clauses;
}
```

I added the `!is_admin()` to conditions, then It fixed.

Also I had another same issue but this time in categories page. For this case I checked plugins and I figured it out the xforwoocommerce (filter) plugin makes duplicate product with different pricing! :| ( I don't know why! )

I disabled it and it fixed, but I think the root cause is  the above code.

Thanks from @benjamin, @grégory-c and @Mtxz!